# Visual Studio Freezes when building projects that have User Controls

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, mobile

I've inherited a Windows Mobile solution that contains multiple user controls, and am experiencing an issue when building the solution in Visual Studio 2008. When the build process reaches "Target Buildasmmeta:" in the build output (which I understand to mean it's working on the user controls portion of the project), the Visual Studio UI freezes. The build continues to go, and eventually it will finish and proceed, however the UI goes white and the devenv.exe process goes red in Resource Monitor. Build times for this solution are very long, with one project that holds 4 user controls is about 8 minutes, and a complete build of the entire solution taking close to an hour.

I have noticed that when building the project Visual Studio uses only one core, which sits at 100% for the duration of the build. Additionally, when Visual Studio is in this locked state, most other Microsoft applications will not work, and present a message saying they're waiting on on the Visual Studio process to complete.

I've setup a script to build my project with MSBuild with multiple cores, which seems to side step these issues completely, however I have had some issues with deploying and debugging when using a direct MSBuild call to build the solution. Build times using this method are typically 4-5 minutes for the entire solution (compared to an hour using a single core).

System specs are an eight core AMD 3.6 ghz (64 bit) processor, 32 gb of ram, 7200 rpm hard drives in a (software) RAID 1, Windows 7 ultimate, and Visual Studio 2008 with SP1. The solution consists of 11 Smart Device projects, and is written in Visual Basic.

Lastly, I'm sure there are some efficiency issues in the code, however these build times just seem excessive, and I'm attempting to reduce them if at all possible. Thank you for any insight you may have on this issue.

Comment: That's going to be hard to diagnose, given that it isn't actually VS that performs the build.  It is MSBuild.exe.  Disable the usual troublemakers like anti-malware.  Turn up msbuild logging verbosity.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon to get insight in what's going on.  If that doesn't help you'll probably need Microsoft Support.

Comment: Based on Hans Passant's suggestions I located the issue. It had to do with a build task: PlatformVerificationTask
which was slowing the build down. Disabling this task resulted in dramatically reduced build times, though I have not yet found a successful method for disabling it at the project level rather than the machine level.